# Magento Bcrypt while new accounts

Tags: magento-1.7

I tried to created the new account and also to receive the mail..My question is that when receive the mail,the password not getting encrypted. Please clarify my question.

Received Mail:

Use the following values when prompted to log in:
E-mail       : sample@gmail.com
Password : testing(Pls explain how to encrypt this part using bcrypt)

Answer (score 0):

I am using password_hash variable in customer mail template instead of password...so its working fine for me.....